# I want to do screenshots using wkhtmltoimage

Tags: php, iframe, terminal, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

[image]php

```
<?php

//リンク先のスクリーンショットを撮影する関数
function screenshot($url){

    // キャプチャしたいWebページのURL
    $url = 'https://appmedia.jp/fategrandorder';

    // キャプチャするイメージの保存先
    $outputImagePath = 'C:/Users/uc100/Programing/xampp/htdocs/codingspace/extention1/screenshot.png';

    // wkhtmltoimageコマンドを組み立て
    $command = "C:/Users/uc100/Programing/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltoimage \"$url\" \"$outputImagePath\"";

    // コマンドを実行
    exec($command, $output, $returnCode);

    if ($returnCode === 0) {
        echo "Screenshot saved.";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

}

?>
```

error statement

```
Loading page (1/2)
Warning: Failed to load https://appmedia.jp/wp-content/themes/appmedia/lib/fategrandorder/images/img/fgo_checker_bg0.jpg (ignore)
Rendering (2/2)
Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Done
Error: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown
```

Uplording Saved image

I want to take a screenshot using wkhtml, but the saved image looks wrong. I am not sure how to solve this problem, so I would appreciate it if someone can help me figure it out.

Comment: This is not a PHP problem. You are just running a command with PHP.